# docker, vagrant sandboxes in php development

Tags: docker, vagrant, docker-machine, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

I have a missunderstanding and i want to find the best approach of a development sandbox environment for a PHP project.

I have a github repo that will host the code , .php, .js (will using webpack with babel), .scss files and different machines for development (windows, mac, ubuntu) .

I want to be able to pull the code from git hub , run a command (like vagrant up) and start a VM / container / sandbox with apache2 , php, nodejs that will run to parse .scss files and .js files into one and then be able to start the server on every platform without having to run gulp locally on developers PC, and then have the XAMPP installed with the correct path for apache2 http folder.

What would be the best approach ? To use vagrant VM with a file config on the repo or docker containers ?

I just want to simplify the development experience and to have this automated tools that start a server, compile sass and babel js.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While I am a big Docker fan, it isn't always the right tool for the job. Docker has principals like immutability and single-service-per-container that probably won't work well for what you're looking to do without a learning curve.

There is a great open-source Vagrant tool called [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) that make configuring a development environment straightforward.

https://puphpet.com/

[image]

From the PuPHPet web site you can configure an image with Apache2, PHP, and NodeJS via their wizard and it will generate a Vagrant file that you to run locally on your workstation. This way you can have all the software you need, without having to deal with installing/maintaining it yourself. It also supports installing databases, queues, and mail applications, should you need them.

For your scenario, I would clone the code from Github onto your workstation (not the VM) and mount it using [Synced Folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) against Vagrant, but still directly accessible by your IDE.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting nice , also i found out Homestead from Laravel , https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead .

Comment: Laravel's Homestead is also an excellent tool. Your question didn't mention your PHP framework, but I would bet you could get either tool to work.